# Align icon top right in Div with CSS

Tags: css

I struggle using CSS to align elements.  I need the MSG Count button to display in the top right of the "detail-row-container" div.  Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="driver-card-wrapper tms-card tms-card-border" (click)="onClick($event)"
  [ngClass]="{'driver-clicked': clicked, 'driver-selected': (selected$ | async)}" appDblClick
  (dblclick)="onDblClick($event)">

  <div class="detail-row-container">
    <!-- ----------------------------------- ROW ------------------------------------ -->
    <div class="detail-row-wrapper">
      <div class="detail-wrapper" style="flex-basis: 62%">
        <span class="detail-text"><b>{{driver?.lastName | titlecase}}, {{driver?.firstName | titlecase}}</b></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ----------------------------------- ROW ------------------------------------ -->
    <div class="detail-row-wrapper">
      <div class="detail-wrapper" style="flex-basis: 140px; color: #AAA">
        <span>{{driver?.id}}</span>
      </div>
      <div class="detail-wrapper">
        <span class="uxd-home md-16"></span>
        <span>{{(driver?.domicile?.site || driver?.domicile?.slic) | uppercase}}</span>
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="!!groupListText">
        <span class="uxd-4-4-alt" matTooltip="{{groupListText}}" matTooltipClass="group-list-tooltip" [matTooltipPosition]="'left'"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- -------------------------------- MSG COUNT --------------------------------- -->

  <div class="tms-mini-mini-btn" *ngIf="driver?.unreadMessages">
    <button mat-mini-fab color="accent">
      <span class="md-10">{{driver?.unreadMessages}}</span>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.driver-card-wrapper {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 4px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 52px;
  min-width: 330px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex-direction: row;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;

  & .uxd-4-4-alt {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}

.driver-selected {
  border: 3px #2196F3 solid !important;

  .driver-card-wrapper {
    border: 3px #2196F3 solid !important;
  }
}

.driver-clicked {
  border: 3px rgba(161, 195, 223, 0.66) solid !important;

  .driver-card-wrapper {
    border: 3px rgba(161, 195, 223, 0.66) solid !important;
  }
}

.detail-row-container {
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
  width: 87%;
}

.detail-row-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex: 1 auto;
}

.detail-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: black;
  font-size: 13px;
  max-width: 60%;
  min-width: 15%;
  flex-basis: 60%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.detail-text {
  white-space: nowrap;
  @include text-ellipsis();
}

.detail-text:hover {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  overflow: visible;
}

.tms-mini-mini-btn>.mat-mdc-mini-fab {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

::ng-deep .group-list-tooltip {
  white-space: pre-line;
  max-width: unset !important;
  font-size: 14px;

  .mdc-tooltip__surface {
    max-width: unset !important;
    font-size: 14px !important;
    font-weight: 400 !important;
    text-align: left !important;
    background-color: rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.8) !important;
  }
}
```

This is how it displays now:

[image: Wrong Display]

I tried setting top and right margins to 0, and even negative pixels but it will not move.

This is how I need it to look:

[image: Correct Display]

Comment: If we put all that code into an HTML file, will it demonstrate the issue?

Comment: If you can't tell, I'm new at all of this.  Is there something more I should have done?  If so, it would have been helpful to tell me so that I could improve on the way I ask a question and/or include code, rather than just leaving a seemingly snide comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used absolute positioning, but if I could change the HTML, I would prefer to put `.tms-mini-mini-btn` in a `.detail-wrapper` in the first `.detail-row-wrapper`.

```css
.driver-card-wrapper {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 4px;
  width: 87%; /* MOVED FROM .detail-row-container */
  height: auto;
  min-height: 52px;
  min-width: 330px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex-direction: row;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;

  position: relative; /* ADDED */


  & .uxd-4-4-alt {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}

.driver-selected {
  border: 3px #2196F3 solid !important;

  .driver-card-wrapper {
    border: 3px #2196F3 solid !important;
  }
}

.driver-clicked {
  border: 3px rgba(161, 195, 223, 0.66) solid !important;

  .driver-card-wrapper {
    border: 3px rgba(161, 195, 223, 0.66) solid !important;
  }
}

.detail-row-container {
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%; /* WAS 87% */
}

.detail-row-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex: 1 auto;
}

.detail-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: black;
  font-size: 13px;
  max-width: 60%;
  min-width: 15%;
  flex-basis: 60%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.detail-text {
  white-space: nowrap;
  @include text-ellipsis();
}

.detail-text:hover {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  overflow: visible;
}

.tms-mini-mini-btn {
    position: absolute; /* ADDED */
    right: 2px;         /* ADDED */
}

.tms-mini-mini-btn>.mat-mdc-mini-fab {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

::ng-deep .group-list-tooltip {
  white-space: pre-line;
  max-width: unset !important;
  font-size: 14px;

  .mdc-tooltip__surface {
    max-width: unset !important;
    font-size: 14px !important;
    font-weight: 400 !important;
    text-align: left !important;
    background-color: rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.8) !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<body style="width: 1px">

<div class="driver-card-wrapper tms-card tms-card-border">

  <div class="detail-row-container">
    <!-- ----------------------------------- ROW ------------------------------------ -->
    <div class="detail-row-wrapper">
      <div class="detail-wrapper" style="flex-basis: 62%">
        <span class="detail-text"><b>Adams, Doris</b></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ----------------------------------- ROW ------------------------------------ -->
    <div class="detail-row-wrapper">
      <div class="detail-wrapper" style="flex-basis: 140px; color: #AAA">
        <span>0221134</span>
      </div>
      <div class="detail-wrapper">
        <span class="uxd-home md-16"></span>
        <span>ATLGA-3039</span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="uxd-4-4-alt"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- -------------------------------- MSG COUNT --------------------------------- -->

  <div class="tms-mini-mini-btn">
    <button mat-mini-fab color="accent">
      <span class="md-10">1</span>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
  
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I'm trying to understand why your changes work.  I see you added relative position to main wrapper and moved 87% width there too, and added absolute position to the button.

Comment: I had to add relative to the `.driver-card-wrapper`, else when I used absolute and right on `.tms-mini-mini-btn` it would try to move it to the right side of the body (or whatever else it found in the tree that was relative). I.e. I am positioning "absolutely" relative to its container, and specifying the container by using relative. If I used `position:relative` instead it would be positioning relative to itself.  
I moved the width to `.detail-row-wrapper` so that is was not wider than `.detail-row-container` as wrapper is the thing I'm positioning inside.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good case for [CSS positioning.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Positioning)

In your parent container:

```css
.driver-card-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  ...
}
```

Then, in the element you want to align:

```css
.tms-mini-mini-btn { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; 
  right: 0;
}
```

You also might have an easier time styling an `<a>` element versus a `<button>`, but that's not directly relevant to your question. Hope this helps.